# GWT export table

Tags: java, gwt, apache-poi, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I am new in GWT and I am working on a project where GWT is used to generate a form. In this form I have added a table in a Vertical panel. Now I want to export this table in excel or CSV. Wondering if someone can help me on this issue.

This is sample code of the entry point class:

```
 public class ItemListEditor implements EntryPoint
   {
   private final Button addRow = new Button("Add Row");
   private final Button save = new Button("Save");
    private final Button next = new Button("Next");
    private final Button upload = new Button("Upload");
    private final Button export = new Button("Export");

    private ItemTable table = null;

}
```

Again, my problem is only to export this table- like when click on export button, system will ask for the location. 
I can provide more information if needed.
Please help on this issue

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you get the export working outside of GWT? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I know writing to excel from database as java application. But I dont know where to start to get the table exported in GWT

Comment: This problem is resolved!!!

- Inside my servlet I have implemented the excel file with apache POI as you suggested. 
- On gwt part I have redirect with servlet url that work absolutely fine as I wanted.
Thanks for the advice AKASH, you just saved my life!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `HTTPServlet` class, inside the `doGet()` method of the servlet create a `HSSFWorbook` using the Apache Poi jar, write your data in the sheet, write the workbook in the response part of `servlet`.
Map the servlet in your web.xml file and finally, use this servlet url inside your button handler..

EDITED ----->

```
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
public void onClick(ClickEvent arg0) {

    exlGenerationServiceAsync.excelReportObjects(new AsyncCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
                            arg0.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Object arg0) {
                            Window.open(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "url", "", "");
                        }
                    });

                }
}
```

Servlet mapping inside the web.xml file----->

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>excelFile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.server.excelFileServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>excelFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/yourUrl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Where excelFileServlet is my servlet class.

Inside Servlet class---->

```
  File file = new File("Path Where you want to write your excel file");
  response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
  response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Excel_Report_Name.xls");
  response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    try{
         OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
         int bytes;
         while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
         responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
     }
     responseOutputStream.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println("Inside Try/catch");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Akash! It will be a great help if you can share some example or code. Specially, passing sheet to the Button and then downloading data to client machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot Akash. I will definitely try this :) 
Is there any active code on the net, regarding this???

Comment: @user3708825:- Sorry for late reply,i would've been glad in searching any link for you but my company has blocked all web sites except handful of web sites.. :( but actually you if you google, you will easily find one, because long back i also learnt through this..

Comment: Hi Akash, Thanks!I am using GWT as support, only in one form where I am rendering a table. Wondering where should I put my servlet in GWT? I have the excel created. Now don't know where to keep servlet and how to call it to download the file.

Comment: Servlet resides in the server side packages and servlet path is mapped in your web.xml file. check i have edited and provided the sample servlet url mapping in the answer.

Comment: I have GWT 1.5! :( I created an external servlet outside of GWT and tried to call it from gwt client. Just realized my version of GWT doesnt support ClickHandler.
Is there anyway to export list object data through RPC???? so that user can download file with save options?? live code will be helpful.

Comment: Did you tried using Event listener ?? [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/GettingStartedEvents)

Comment: Hi Akash, I have tried with Servlet. 
- Inside my servlet I have implemented the excel file with apache POI as you suggested. 
- On gwt part I have redirect with servlet url that work absolutely fine as I wanted.
Thanks for the advice, you just saved my life!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for some quick and raw exportation, you can give a try to https://code.google.com/p/gwt-table-to-excel/. The project is not very active.

Otherwise, if you want to have more control on the formatting and data you have to send the content of the table to the server side using RPC or other, and then you can use Apache POI to export it as you do usually in Java.

Comment: Thanks outellou! It will be helpful if you can refer some active code on this issue